# What are (if there are any) the major applications/implications of relativistic electrodynamics in engineering?

Tags: electromagnetism, theory, physics

I was wondering about the relativistic and covariant formulation of classical E&M and Maxwell's Equations. Does they have any major implication in engineering (not exclusively talking about electrical eng, but i think it might be the majorly affected)?

I've once heard that relativistic electrodynamics plays a role in artificial neural networks, but i couldn't find any related bibliography. 
So, to sum up

**What are the major applications of relativistic electrodynamics to engineering?**

Comment: Please don't close this, it tickles my curiosity. The physics SE could be a better place for this question though.